# Express a function as difference of convex functions (DC)

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

is there a way to express the function $$1-\exp \Big( \frac{-\max(0,x)^2}{\alpha} \Big)$$ as the difference of two convex functions (DC)?

Thanks

Comment: AFAICS, $\max(0, x)^2 = x^2$ (as long as $x$ is real).

Comment: As it's written, when $x\leq0$, the exp term is 1 and the whole function is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any smooth function can be decomposed into a difference of convex functions. In this case, the following should work.

We want $f(x)=g(x)-h(x)$, where $g$ and $h$ are the convex functions. Since $f$ is convex for $x < \sqrt{2 \alpha}$, and concave for $x > \sqrt {2\alpha}$, we can let $g=f$ for $x < \sqrt{2 \alpha}$, and $g$ be linear for $x > \sqrt {2\alpha}$. Then by matching up derivatives we get:

$$
g(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & x \le 0 \\
1 - e^{-x^2/\alpha} & 0<x\le \sqrt{2\alpha} \\
1 - e^{-2}\left(\sqrt\frac{8}{\alpha} x - 3\right) & x > \sqrt{2\alpha}
\end{cases}
$$

$$
h(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & x\le \sqrt{2\alpha} \\
e^{-x^2/\alpha} - e^{-2}\left(\sqrt\frac{8}{\alpha} x - 3\right) & x > \sqrt{2\alpha}
\end{cases}
$$